# Rails ActiveRecord callbacks dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I am trying to update a rails record if a duplicate exists as follow:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :update_rating_if_already_exists

  def update_rating_if_already_exists
    original_rating = Rating.where(user: self.user, article: self.article)
    if original_rating.blank?
      true
    else
      original_rating[0].update_attribute(:score, self.score)
      false
    end
  end
end
```

the problem however is that when I use `after_create` as above, this will not work for normal usage from controller action, as the controller will first build a new instance of the class with given params and then `save` (not `create`) the new object.

However, if I change the above to an `after_save`, it takes care of the controller problem, but then leads to another problem:

```
original_rating[0].update_attribute(:score, self.score)
```

will try to update the original record with a `save` method, which will also trigger the `before_save`...and on, and on... and this leads to a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error.

This is the dilemma now and my question is how could I go about this?

Thanks for all contributions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `before_save` with a `new_record?` condition to avoid executing the callback on an `update_attribute` call.

```
before_save :update_rating_if_already_exists, if: :new_record?

def update_rating_if_already_exists
  # method code
end
```